# Flush valve nut doesn't fit new 3" dual flush valve

Tags: toilet

I have a 2 piece Quality Craft toilet.  The dual flush valve is leaking so I purchased a new Fluidmaster [dual flush valve](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0852925D3).  The plastic flush valve nut doesn't fit the new Fluidmaster valve.  It appears to be too small.

The Fluidmaster kit didn't come with a flush valve nut.  Fluidmaster support isn't open on the weekend, but I wondered if they might send a nut.

Any other suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Have you verified that you have a 3inch valve?  There are others available that supposedly come with a nut.

Comment: I measured the diameter of the white and blue valve above and they were both 3".   Yeah I just noticed that ... I might have to get one.  I'm going to try this just to get the nut that it says is 3" : https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B08RCMQK5C

Comment: I called Fluidmaster this morning and they are going to send a flush valve nut.  I'll post the results after I get that in a few days.